# How to Have an empty row if query result couldn't find anything with one assigned value under one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, plsql, database-administration

I am trying to create a view that will give me a total usage,total amount  and a nickname for a client. if nothing was found it will leave the other columns null but display the client name and nickname. I simplified my query and changed the table name and column for convenience. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

here is my code:

```
select 
                 Client_Name= (case
                             when account = 123 then 'John'
                             when account = 234 then 'Doe'
                             end),
                  Total_Usage = sum(Credit_Used),
                  Total_Amount = sum(debit),
                  Nickname = (case 
                              when account = 123 then 'J'
                              when account = 234 then  'D'
                              end)
  from           myTable
  where          year= 2015
  group by =     (case
                 when account = 123 then 'John'
                 when account = 234 then 'Doe'
                 end),
                 (case 
               when account = 123 then 'J'
               when account = 234 then  'D'
               end)
```

I am getting an answer like this :

```
John 34  3 J
```

I want something like this :

```
John 34  3 J
 Doe   0  0 D
```

Comment: And thanks for editing!

Comment: Do you have a table for account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have the table for users, and you have a huge case/when expression... You really SHOULD create the users table! It would be a nightmare to maintain the 2 large when/case expressions correctly!

If you still prefer to opt out from creating users table, just like Sami suggested, you should create an inline view and OUTER JOIN it to your main table. Select statement similar to the one below should do it.

> NB: I've used syntax that is more familiar to me, but that should work
>   in SQL Server as well.

```
select b.client_name,
       sum(a.credit_used) total_usage,
       sum(a.debit) total_amount,
       b.nickname
  from MyTable a
       right outer join
       (select 123 account_id, 'John' client_name, 'J' nickname union all
        select 234, 'Doe','D') b
       on
       (a.account = b.account_id)
 where a.year = 2015
 group by b.client_name, b.nickname
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the database doesn't have rows for that, you cannot do it this way.

If you have a separate table for users, you can use an OUTER join to get this. Surely you have that and don't have a huge CASE WHEN thing in the query itself?

If it's only for two users, you can also have an OUTER join with a simple select/union structure that gives the user IDs and names, but it isn't very good way to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately no to both questions, I don't have a table for first column and I have a huge when case statement for first and last column , I will try to create a temp table to keep my first and last row and use a outer join by a store procedure instead. I will let you know how that works out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually outer join this to a dummy table and do:

```
when account = 234 or account is null then 'Doe'
```

Then do it for all the entries, just outer-join it, since you're anyway hard-coding the names ...